# Will python requests raise Timeout if a firewall blocks packets?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use the Python requests library version 2.27.1 to implement a sanity check of a URL by POST-ing with a timeout parameter.  My Python 3 (interpreter version 3.9) class constructor sends the request like this, where timeout is an integer value 10:

```
    logger.debug('__init__: checking network access to url %s', self.url)
    response = requests.post(f'{self.url}/validate', timeout=timeout)
```

I am testing in a lab where the firewall allows DNS name resolution but blocks the traffic to the URL.  I thought the timeout parameter would help me detect the failure to connect (the missing connectivity), but the request just waits indefinitely for a response.  I interrupted it after a few minutes; maybe it would have timed out eventually and I just didn't wait long enough? But for a sanity test I'd like the timeout to be in a few seconds, not minutes.

I know I can supply a tuple as the timeout parameter, with the connect timeout separate from the transfer timeout, but I am not sure splitting up the args is a fix for my current problem.

Please guide me if I have misinterpreted the doc.  Sorry I cannot link to the doc page right now because the project is having domain-name problems :( :( If you start here you'll see it too: https://docs.python-requests.org/

Comment: timeout also supports float numbers as param. test with `timeout=0.01` to check if you get timeout and catching exception is working properly.

Comment: Also note, timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds). If no timeout is specified explicitly, requests do not time out.

Comment: Thanks @BijayRegmi right but I'm not asking about the missing-timeout-parameter case. I am also not clear why testing with a timeout of 1/10 of a second will yield a timeout when 10 seconds does not, but sure I can give it a try.